# How can I calculate earned premium in Power BI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Calculating Earned premium with Power BI.

Hello, i am pretty new to Power BI and i am very stuck on the calculation for Earned premium with power bi for my project. I have tried to look up solutions online but for some reason they just would not work for me.

Background:
Earned premium for insurance companies is calculated as follow:
Earned Premium  = Amount Paid * Days In Current Period / Total Days of Cover
For example, if you paid $100 for 1 year of insurance, then in the month of March you will earn $8.49:

Earned Premium = $100 * 31 (Days in March)  / 365 (Days of insurance purchased).

Issues:
I have my premium broken down to premium per day and was hoping that i can just times it by number of dates in the covered period.

```
Earned prmeium = 
CALCULATE(
   SUM( 'pre_staging scheduled_item_coverage'[Premium per day]
    *
        COUNTROWS(
            DATESBETWEEN(
            Calender[Date],
            IF(
                FIRSTDATE(Calender[Date])>=MIN('pre_staging scheduled_item_coverage'[Premium start date]),
                FIRSTDATE(Calender[Date]),MIN('pre_staging scheduled_item_coverage'[Premium start date])
            ),
            IF(
                LASTDATE(Calender[Date])<=MAX('pre_staging scheduled_item_coverage'[Expiring date]),
                LASTDATE(Calender[Date]),MAX('pre_staging referral_types'[expiry_date])
            )
            )
        )
```

I do not know where my code went wrong up to this point.

I am hoping someone experienced will be able to direct me the right way.

Thank you!

Tom.

Comment: What are your table relationships, and what issue are you having right now with this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Earned prmeium = 

SUMX(
   'Calendar',
    SUMX('pre_staging scheduled_item_coverage',
        IF( 
            AND(
                'pre_staging scheduled_item_coverage'[Premium start date] <= 'Calendar'[Date],
                'pre_staging scheduled_item_coverage'[Expiring Date] > 'Calendar'[Date]
            ),
            'pre_staging scheduled_item_coverage'[Premium per day], BLANK()
        )
    )
)
```

This iterates over each policy for each day. If that day is within the policy period, add the premium per day.